# WMI command to connect to remote machines and retrieve Software Version and Installation Date

Tags: powershell, wmi, wmi-query, wmi-service

I need help in connecting to 2 remote machines running Windows XP and retrive details of a software version and installation date.
I am new to WMI and would appreciate if someone could guide me in the right direction.

At the moment , I execute the below command manually on the machines.
wmic product where "Vendor like '%xyz%'" get Name, Version

Answer (score 3):

I will give you a much simple version written in PowerShell.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select Version,InstallDate | Export-Csv -Path C:\Scripts\Software.csv
```

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

in order to list the installed software in a local or remote machine using the WMI you must use the  [`Win32_Product`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394378%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) wmi class.

check [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156540.aspx) vbscript sample

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("c:\scripts\software.tsv", True)
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
 & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colSoftware = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
 ("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product")
objTextFile.WriteLine "Caption" & vbtab & _
"Description" & vbtab & "Identifying Number" & vbtab & _
"Install Date" & vbtab & "Install Location" & vbtab & _
"Install State" & vbtab & "Name" & vbtab & _
"Package Cache" & vbtab & "SKU Number" & vbtab & "Vendor" & vbtab _
 & "Version"
For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
 objTextFile.WriteLine objSoftware.Caption & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.Description & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.IdentifyingNumber & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.InstallLocation & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.InstallState & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.Name & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.PackageCache & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.SKUNumber & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.Vendor & vbtab & _
 objSoftware.Version
Next
objTextFile.Close
```

if you need use this wmi class from another language like C#, Vb Net or Delphi you can use a tool like the [`WMI Code Creator`](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) or [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) to help you to build the WQL sentence.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the response. I get an error 'Path Not Found' when I execute the script. (I have specified the computer name in the strComputer)

Comment: if you see the second line of the sample code, this create a file called `software.tsv` in the `C:\scripts` folder, this folder must exist. anyway you can use the tools which I recommended you to see another examples to how access this wmi class.